# Prove that $\varliminf_{n \to \infty}\left(\inf_{x\in X} f_n(x)\right) \leq \inf_{x\in X}\left( \varliminf_{n \to \infty} f_n (x)\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

We also know that $f_n(x)$ is bounded for every $n\in\mathbb{N}, x\in X$.

Firstly using liminf definition I rewrote

$\varliminf_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \inf_{k\geq n} f_k(x)$

And we know that this inequality holds:

$\varliminf_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \inf_{k\geq n} f_k(x) \geq \inf_{k\geq n} f_k(x)$

Then i took infinum from both sides:

$\inf_{x\in X}\left( \varliminf_{n \to \infty} f_n (x) \right) \geq \inf_{x\in X}\left( \inf_{k\geq n} f_k(x) \right)$

And finally using monotocity I got:

$\varliminf_{n \to \infty}\left( \inf_{x\in X}\varliminf_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) \right)\geq \varliminf_{n \to \infty}\left( \inf_{k\geq n} \left( \inf_{x\in X} f_k(x) \right) \right)$

And now i want to get rid of the inner liminf from the left side, but I can't figure out how.

Could someone help me out with the proof? I really need this proven for my real analysis course :)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to mse! What have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^. In particular, can you mention some of the things you tried that led to dead ends?

Answer (score 0):

Using perhaps a cleaner notation makes it fall into place:

Since
$$\tag{1}
\inf_{y\in X}f_n(y)\le f_n(x)\,,\quad \forall x\in X\,,
$$
it is trivial that
$$\tag{2}
\varliminf_{n \to \infty}\Big( \inf_{y\in X}f_n(y)\Big)\le \varliminf_{n \to \infty}  f_n(x)\,,\quad \forall x\in X\,.
$$
Now take the inf on the RHS and you are done.

Your formula
$$\varliminf_{n \to \infty}\left( \inf_{x\in X}\varliminf_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) \right)\geq \varliminf_{n \to \infty}\left( \inf_{k\geq n} \left( \inf_{x\in X} f_k(x) \right) \right)$$
does not make sense because on the LHS you have two limits of $n\to\infty\,.$